# What is the convex conjugate (fenchel conjugate) of $f(x)=\lambda \|x\|_1$?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

What is the convex conjugate or the fenchel conjugate of $f(x)=\lambda \|x\|_1$?

If $g(x)=\|x\|_1$, the convex conjugate is simply $g^*(x)=\mathbf{1}_{\|x\|_{\infty}\leq 1}(x)$.

However, I am not so sure when the constant $\lambda$ is multiplied to the norm.

> $f^*(x)=\sup_y(x^Ty-\lambda\|y\|_1)$ and then I am stuck.

I am guessing the answer is $f^*(x)=\mathbf{1}_{\lambda\|x\|_{\infty}\leq 1}(x)$ but my intuition tells me that is not right.

> My second attempt is $f^*(x)=\sup_y(x^Ty-\lambda\|y\|_1)=\lambda\sup_y(\frac{1}{\lambda}x^Ty-\|y\|_1)=\lambda\mathbf{1}_{\|\frac{x}{\lambda}\|_{\infty}\leq 1}(\frac{x}{\lambda})$

Comment: The convex conjugate of $g(x)=\|x\|_1$ is actually $g^*(x)=\mathbf{1}_{\|x\|_\infty \leq 1}(x)$. The specific norm is important.

Comment: Your second guess is good, but you can do better: if $\|x\|_\infty \leq 1$, what does that say about $x/\lambda$? (And there's a bit of operator overloading happening w.r.t $x$ in that case anyway, so be careful.)

Comment: I updated my answer Michael! Is this correct?

Comment: I am not sure how do I remove the operator overloading. @MichaelGrant

Comment: Not quite, you put it in both places. You either do $\mathbf{1}_{\|z\|_\leq 1}(x/\lambda)$ or $\mathbf{1}_{\|x/\lambda\|_\leq 1}(x)$ but not both. But you have the right idea.

Comment: Sorry Michael, I'm clueless at this point. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said, you're almost there. Let's look at the general case. Given
$$f^*(y) = \sup_x x^T y - f(x)$$
we can now do $g(x) = \lambda f(x)$ as follows:
$$g^*(y) = \sup_x x^T y - g(x) = \sup_x x^T y - \lambda f(x) = \lambda \left( \sup_x \lambda^{-1} x^T y - f(x) \right) = \lambda f^*(\lambda^{-1} y)$$
So now that we have the general case, let's choose the specific case:
$$f(x) = \|x\|_1, \quad g(x) = \lambda \|x\|_1 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad g^*(y) = \lambda f^*(\lambda^{-1} y) = \lambda \mathbf{1}_{\|\cdot\|_\infty\leq 1}(\lambda^{-1} y)$$ 
Now we can do a couple of simplifications. First, note that $\lambda \mathbf{1}(\cdot) = \mathbf{1}(\cdot)$ for any $\lambda >0$, so we can drop that outer $\lambda$. Secondly, note that (again, for $\lambda>0$) 
$$\|\lambda^{-1} y \|_\infty \leq 1 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \|y\|_\infty \leq \lambda$$
So finally, we have in its simplest form:
$$g(x) = \lambda \|x\|_1 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad g^*(y) = \mathbf{1}_{\|\cdot\|_\infty \leq \lambda}(y).$$